# How can I MediaRecord the lowest-bitrate screenshare video possible alongside HQ audio?

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

I've been exploring some approaches to recording `system` audio on PC through Chrome, and I've been successful using the MediaRecorder API. I end up with a webm file of the shared screen. As long as the user clicks the button to share audio too, the result is great.

**Issue:** I don't want the video part recorded. I haven't found a way to record 'only' the audio—It seems it has to record video+audio to work. Now that I have to record the video, **how can I apply media constraints make the screenshare video as small a footprint as possible so as to keep memory and CPU demands low?**

These recordings will be anywhere from 2 seconds to 15 minutes long.

```
const screenSharingConstraints = {
        video: {
            width: 160
            },
        audio: true
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(screenSharingConstraints()).then(onSuccess, onMediaStreamError);
```

Here's what I'm doing with the stream:

```
let onSuccess = function (stream) {
  var options = {audioBitsPerSecond : 32000, mimeType : encoding_mimetype, videoBitsPerSecond : 250}
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

On running this, I still get a huge screen-share dimension size. How can I make this as small as possible in the definition from JavaScript?

MediaRecorder Docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder
Media Constraints
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the audio?

```
const screenSharingConstraints = {
        audio: true
}
```

should give just audio output.  If you are concerned about bandwidth with the default settings:

```
var constraints = { audio: {sampleRate: 11025},
};
```

would give you 11 KBPS audio (obviously change the parameter as desired).

If you want the file to be a video, you can make the width and height as small as possible, but also make the framerate 1 KBPS (example below using JS variables):

```
var constraints = { audio: {sampleRate: audioBitrate},
    video:{
        width: { min: 100, ideal: width, max: 1920 },
        height: { min: 100, ideal: height, max: 1080 },
        frameRate: {ideal: framerate}
    }
};
```

I've got a working example of this for video (with adjustable params) at https://livestream.streamclarity.com[enter link description here](https://livestream.streamclarity.com) and the code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/dougsillars/browserLiveStream).  The backend for the live stream is [api.video](https://api.video)

Comment: When I use screenSharingConstraints = {audio: true}, I get a "TypeError: Failed to execute 'getDisplayMedia' on 'MediaDevices': Audio only requests are not supported"; this happens in Chrome on Mac. Here's chromium code that denies that access: https://code.immersaview.com/remotes/chromium-third_party/-/blob/472f37b3a288783f6733054a0b3940c479f71330/blink/renderer/modules/mediastream/user_media_request.cc#L351 . The constraints you sent do work, but is there a way to query the minimum constraints that still work on a browser?

Comment: If you set your ideal to a *higher* resolution than the webcam can support, the browser will go with the resolution of the camera.

If you set the ideal width to 1, I assume the browser will go with the lowest resolution possible.

Comment: I am able to stream just audio in my code.  I notice you are using: navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(constraints)

I am using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)

The display version requires video :)